# Granting write access to tex when using solides3d

Tags: texniccenter, ps2pdf, pst-solides3d

There is an obstacle when using `action=writesolid` in `pst-solides3d`. Mainly, I need to generate some datafiles for some solides like the following. I want to perform some slices and the examples use this approach

```
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-4)(3,4)
\psset{viewpoint=50 40 30 rtp2xyz,lightsrc=viewpoint,Decran=40,}
\psSurface[ngrid=.25 .25,incolor=gray,action=writesolid,file=./silla](-2,-2)(2,2){x y mul}
\end{pspicture}
```

Which should generate the following files

- silla-couleurs.dat
- silla-faces.dat
- silla-sommets.dat
- silla-io.dat

I knew that I would bump into security issues `Error: /invalidaccessfile in -file-`

I am using WinXP and I would like to know how to configure my system to set an exception to allow me to write such datafiles but the manual entry on the subject is beyond my comprehension

> Windows: Within the menue Options, the option Security of files must be turned to unchecked.
>
> **pst-solides User Manual: Chapter 5 - Usage of external files**

PS: I may have used an incorrect title for this question (and tags for that matter), any suggestions on improving (or edits) are more than welcome

Comment: The question title is perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a safety measure, Ghostscript and Distiller don't allow, by default, file reading and writing operations, `... (r) file` / `...(w) file`, during PS to PDF conversion.

What you need to do is:

```
ps2pdf -dNOSAFER mydoc.ps
```

With Distiller, add option `-F` to the commandline.

Comment: Excellent, I'll leave the details for `TeXnicCenter` here also.